# How to update profile card to content Item programmatically?

Tags: personalization

The client has a requirement where they want to automate content profiling based on the meta keywords. For example, if the user creates a content item and add meta keyword as `"Cycle"` then while saving an item that Item should automatically associate with corresponding Profile like `"Cyclist"`. The author is not required to associate profile manually in the Experience editor.

I have tried to update `Profile` in the `tracking field` on an item but it seems to be `read-only`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try this? https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2017/05/28/tag-sitecore-content-with-profile-card-programmatically/

Comment: Perfect. It worked.

Comment: @x3mxray Can you take the notes from Hishaamn's post and make it an answer. So we don't lose it if his blog goes away

Comment: @ChrisAuer Done.

Answer (score 3):

Notes with code from Hishaamn Namooya blog post:

The **TagProfile** method retrieves the different profile presets (*Profile Cards*) and then update the tracking field of content item accordingly with the *Profile Keys*:

```
public void TagProfile(Item contentItem, Guid profileId)
{
    // retrieve tracking information 
    ProfileUtil.GetProfiles(contentItem, out TrackingField trackingField);
    var trackingValue = contentItem.Fields["__Tracking"].Value;

    // get needed profile
    var profile = trackingField.Profiles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProfileID.Guid.Equals(profileId));
    if (profile != null)
    {
        var profileItem = new ProfileItem(profile.GetProfileItem());

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        // TODO: implement logic that you need here
        // iterate through profile cards and add NEEDED key/values to presets dictionary
        foreach (var card in profileItem.ProfileCards)
        {
            dictionary.Add(card.InnerItem.Key, 10);
        }

        profile.SaveToField = true;
        profile.Presets = dictionary;

        SetProfileKeys(profile, profileItem);

        TrackingField.UpdateKeyValues(profile);
    }

    // update "Tracking" field raw-value of contentItem

    XDocument document = string.IsNullOrEmpty(trackingValue) ? new XDocument(new XElement("tracking")) : XDocument.Parse(trackingValue);
    XElement xelement1 = document.Element("tracking");
    if (xelement1 == null)
    {
        xelement1 = new XElement("tracking");
        document.Add(xelement1);
    }
    List<XElement> list = xelement1.Elements("profile").ToList();

    foreach (XElement t in list)
    {
        t.Remove();
    }

    foreach (XElement xelement2 in trackingField.Profiles.Where(x => x.SaveToField).Select(x => x.ToXElement()))
        xelement1.Add(xelement2);

    // save
    using (new SecurityDisabler())
    {
        contentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
        contentItem.Fields["__Tracking"].Value = document.ToString();
        contentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

The **SetProfileKeys** method is used to set the different profile keys:

```
public void SetProfileKeys(ContentProfile profile, ProfileItem profileItem) 
{ 
   foreach (ProfileKeyItem profileKeyItem in profileItem.Keys.ToList()) 
   { 
       ProfileKeyItem keyItem = profileKeyItem; 
       if (profile.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => string.Compare(k.Key, keyItem.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0) == null) 
       { 
           ContentProfileKeyData key = new ContentProfileKeyData(keyItem) 
           { 
                Value = keyItem.GetDefaultValue() 
            }; 
            profile.AddKey(key); 
        } 
    } 


    foreach (ContentProfileKeyData key in profile.Keys.Where(key => key.ProfileDefinitionId == Guid.Empty)) 
    { 
        profile.RemoveKey(key); 
    } 

    TrackingField.UpdateKeyValues(profile); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below blog explains exacts steps to achieve this functionality.

https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2017/05/28/tag-sitecore-content-with-profile-card-programmatically/

I have created Persona Tags and modified Persona Template to refer it as multi-list. I have customized OnItemsave Pipeline to update Profile in content Item depending on Meta keywords(Which is mapped to Persona Tags)  used.

Thanks to Hishaamn Namooya.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, we try and avoid link only answers. If that link goes away, the answer is invalid. This is why I requested x3mxray create the blog in an answer.